# How to swap two opposite corner pieces of a solved face?

Tags: rubiks-cube

I have a solved white face but I want to swap two opposite corner pieces of the white face to form a T-shape on the back face. How can I achieve this without messing up the other pieces on those two faces?

Comment: To swap the two *front* corners of the "solved" top white face, do LD'FDDF'DL'.

Comment: Which pieces form this T shape? Or do you not want to change *any* cubie on the back face? Do you just mean you have the other two of the first layer in their correct positions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the question so far it would appear that you mean you have solved the white face (`U`) and have all of the first layer - the ring around that face is all of the correct colour - except for to opposite corner cubies like so, or a mirror image (or colour change):

[image]

...and you want to swap these two without changing the ring except at those cubies (thus fully solving the top layer).

This is quite easily remedied by just using the bottom layer, one quick way would be to perform:

`R2 F' R2 D2 R2 F R2` - [Singmaster notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube#Solutions)

The first three moves will set the two corners onto opposite locations in the bottom layer with everything else out of the way; the `D2` swaps them; and the last three put everything back again.

Comment: I would suggest tring to approach the cube less face-by face and more block by block... Check out [this method](http://lar5.com/cube/index.html) for example.

Comment: A shorter move sequence is R L D2 R' L'.